# Terraform to show available key pair name in aws

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on an automation so for that I want to know if terraform can just show me current available key pair name (ssh key created by users manually on AWS UI) which are present on AWS?

Once I get the key pair name then I will be using a loop to import then using import command.

terraform import aws_key_pair.importexample

Comment: No, this is not something you can do with Terraform. Just use the `awscli` to list your keys: ` aws ec2 describe-key-pairs`

Answer (score 2):

You could import those resources - but I suspect they will be of limited use initially, other than being able to delete them, or perhaps recreate them and then re-issue - you would also need to issue a replacement private key.

The limited use is due to the fact that there will be no private key (at least not in your posession), and no public key (easily) available. :-/

You can use the `aws_key_pair` data source to get information about a specific `aws_key_pair` or all of them.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/key_pair

eg.

```
data "aws_key_pair" "example" {
  key_name = "test"
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Component"
    values = ["web"]
  }
}

output "fingerprint" {
  value = data.aws_key_pair.example.fingerprint
}

output "name" {
  value = data.aws_key_pair.example.key_name
}

output "id" {
  value = data.aws_key_pair.example.id
}
```

A simple way to get the public key would use EC2 or ECS, then **capture** it to allow you to insert it into the `aws_key_pair` resource in your terraform code.

Perhaps you could write a `user_script` to run on boot and push the contents of the `authorized_keys` file to an S3 bucket - but you would have to do that for as many times as you have `aws_key_pair`s...

Luckilly terraform will do that in parallel if there are no dependancies to prevent it. :-D

So if you get the list of `aws_key_pair` entries from the data source, and then loop through them with a `for_each` you could do it, I guess... YMMV

You'll still be in a situation of having to re-create each `aws_key_pair` thought **[see note from Hashicorp below]**, but at least you could do so knowing you now have the public key, and as it will be IaC life would be better. ;-)

If you craft your `terraform output` right, you could make life a little easier for importing the resources with `terraform import`

You could also go the `awscli` route and generate the necessary `terraform` code to import and create the resources in one shot.

This snippet may be of use to you if you use `aws-vault` - though obviously it can be easilly modified if not.

```
for profile in $(aws-vault list --profiles | sort);
do
  echo -e "####################\nProfile: $profile";
  for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions | jq -r '.Regions[].RegionName' | sort);
  do
    echo "  Region: $region";
    aws-vault exec $profile aws --region $region ec2 describe-key-pairs;
  done;
done
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to loop over the results and inject the apropriate values into the `key_pair` resource once you have each public key to hand;

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "perhaps-use-a-template-for-this" {

  key_name        = var.key_name
  public_key      = var.public_key

  tags = var.tags
}
```

#### Note from Hashicorp:

> Key Pairs can be imported using the `key_name`, e.g.,

```
$ terraform import aws_key_pair.deployer deployer-key
```

> NOTE: The AWS API does not include the public key in the response, so terraform apply will attempt to replace the key pair. There is currently no supported workaround for this limitation.